# Use of producer.properties and consumer.properties file in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Inside the Kafka package there is an config folder which has various config files. This folder has  consumer.properties and  producer.properties files, are these configurations used when we run the Kafka Cluster and when our code connects to kafka cluster or are these just sample property files? The documentation is not very clear on this.

We have an automation job that create and deploys new kafka nodes and I need to know whether any changes needs to be made in these files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The consumer.properties and producer.properties files are just examples for configuring a consumer or producer application.
They can be used by the `kafka-console-consumer` console application for example with the `--consumer.config` paramenter by the `kafka-console-producer` console application with the `--producer.config` parameter.
In any case even server.properties and zookeeper.properties files are example of configuration for broker and zookeeper.

Comment: Thats what i thought was well, Thank you.

Comment: How can I set this parameters in a spark java program*