# Spark: get very big message from kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to receive very big message with spark from kafka. 
But  it seems that spark have a limit for the size of the message that can be read. 
I have changed in kafka config to be able to consume and send big message but this is not enough (I think this is related to spark not to kafka) because when using kafka.consumer script I don't have any problem displaying the content of the message.

Maybe this is related to `spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.cache.maxCapacity` but I don't know how to set it in a spark java based program.

Thank you.

**Update**

I am using this to connect to Kafka normally args[0] is zookeeper address and the args[1] is the groupID.

```
if (args.length < 4) {
        System.err.println("Usage: Stream Car data <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("stream cars data");

    final JavaSparkContext jSC = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    // Creer le contexte avec une taille de batch de 2 secondes
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(jSC,new Duration(2000));

    int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] topics = args[2].split(",");

    for (String topic: topics) {
        topicMap.put(topic, numThreads);
    }

    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, args[0], args[1], topicMap);

    JavaDStream<String> data = messages.map(Tuple2::_2);
```

and this is the error that I get

```
18/04/13 17:20:33 WARN scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Error reported by receiver for stream 0: Error handling message; exiting - kafka.common.MessageSizeTooLargeException: Found a message larger than the maximum fetch size of this consumer on topic Hello-Kafka partition 0 at fetch offset 3008. Increase the fetch size, or decrease the maximum message size the broker will allow.
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:90)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
        at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
        at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver$MessageHandler.run(KafkaInputDStream.scala:133)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Could you please provide any error logs that helps you claim that "spark have a limit for the size of the message that can be read"? Also, are you using spark-streaming or structured streaming to ingest data from Kafka?

Comment: what do you mean by spark-streaming or structured streaming

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-Spark-streaming-and-Spark-structured-streaming-Is-Spark-structured-streaming-the-future-of-Spark-streaming

Comment: I have posted the code can you figure it out from there. thanks for helping me

Comment: Please check if the solution solves the issue for you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Kafka you are using, you need to set the following consumer config in the `consumer.properties` file available (or to be created) in Kafka config files.

for version 0.8.X or below.

```
fetch.message.max.bytes
```

for Kafka version 0.9.0 or above, set

```
fetch.max.bytes
```

to appropriate values based on your application.

Eg. `fetch.max.bytes=10485760`

Refer [this](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020347/how-can-i-send-large-messages-with-kafka-over-15mb?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I have set it. but I think that file is not considered in the config

Comment: according to this, this files are just examples
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321503/use-of-producer-properties-and-consumer-properties-file-in-apache-kafka?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a solution to my problem, In fact as I said in the comment the files in the config file are just examples and they aren't taken into consideration when stating the server. So all the configuration of consumer including `fetch.message.max.bytes` need to be done in the consumer code.

And this is how I did it:

```
if (args.length < 4) {
        System.err.println("Usage: Stream Car data <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("stream cars data");

    final JavaSparkContext jSC = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    // Creer le contexte avec une taille de batch de 2 secondes
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(jSC,new Duration(2000));

    int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] topics = args[2].split(",");

    for (String topic: topics) {
        topicMap.put(topic, numThreads);
    }



    Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(topics));
    Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", args[0]);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", args[1]);
    kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", args[0]);
    kafkaParams.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", "1100000000");



    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages=KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            kafkaParams,
            topicMap,MEMORY_ONLY() );


    JavaDStream<String> data = messages.map(Tuple2::_2);
```